# Can't call a part of an object after parsed as JSON in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, rest, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make some code that can pull from an API and pull out a piece from the response. My code is below.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://[API_URL]', options);
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var firstCall = response.getContentText();
  var JsonObj = JSON.parse(firstCall);
  Logger.log(firstCall['id']);
  sheet.appendRow(['successfully connected to API.']);
  sheet.appendRow([Logger.getLog()]);
```

A sample response from the API is below.

```
[{"id":12345678901234567,"name":"email@email.com - someText"}]
```

When I try to run the first code, it completes the code, logging the above line and undefined. My goal is to get just the ID from the string. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. To keep it simple, do it like this:

```
function getURLFromSite(){

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
     var JsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
       Logger.log(JsonObj[1].name);

}
```

Here's `JsonObj` is like an array which you can access using `JsonObj[0]`, `JsonObj[1]` and `JsonObj[2]`.

To access properties like `id` or `name`, just use the dot notation like `JsonObj[0].id` or `JsonObj[1].name`.

Comment: thank you so much! One more question: when it prints the id, it prints it as a formatted number, like 1.2454656E362, not like 123455353645. How would I get it to print out the number as a string?